# Virtual Machne : Is it possible to get data from database in VM?

Tags: database, virtual-machine

My main OS is `Linux Ubuntu 16.04`.

And I will run `Windows` OS on my virtual machine. The reason I use virtual machine is to crawl data and save them in `database(MySQL)`, which would be stored in HDD partition of `VM` . Since the data crawl API works only in `Windows`, I have to keep it in the virtual machine.

What I wonder is that if I implement this system, can I get or read the data "in my main machine, **`Ubuntu`**"?.

Comment: Which virtual machine technology are you using? VirtualBox? Qemu? Please specify: the way for interacting is different. In any case I guess you have to understand the topology of the virtual network between host and guest machines.

Answer (score 0):

Just set you connection string (ip address, port) equal to your vm's ip address. First make a ping to vm's ip address from your main PC to make sure you have access.